# Stripe -- A way to transfer using source_transaction with paymentIntents

Tags: javascript, firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying get customer payment using PaymentIntents and if the status is `succeeded`, create transfers to the correct stripe connect account while using source_transaction.

payment.id in this case was `pi_1I7xsjL98Injb3kNT74IwMK8` and I got the error `No such charge: pi_1I7xsjL98Injb3kNT74IwMK8` which led to the `resource_missing` error. It makes sense since I am passing in a paymentIntents Id, but is there a way I could use `source_transaction` while using paymentIntents?

A sample of what I am doing in my code is below!

```
return stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: data.amount,
            currency: data.currency,
            customer: stripeCustomerId,
            payment_method: data.paymentMethodId,
            off_session: false,
            confirm: true,
            confirmation_method: 'manual',
            setup_future_usage: 'off_session',
            // transfer_group: idempotencyKey
        }, { idempotencyKey })
    }).then(payment => {
       
        if (payment.status == 'succeeded') {        
            let transferPromises = []
            transferPromises.push(
                stripe.transfers.create({
                    amount: Math.ceil(payment.amount_received * 0.9),
                    currency: 'usd',
                    destination: creator.data().stripeConnectId,
                    source_transaction: payment.id,
                    // transfer_group: idempotencyKey,
                })
            )
```

Comment: If you get to `then` at all, then it was successful - it would throw in the case of a failure.

I don't see - and you're not indicating - where you're getting that error, but it's likely related to how you're using (or not using) the `Stripe-Account` header.

Can you provide more details on where/how you're getting the error?

Comment: Did you eventually get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Ok Found the answer.
"When you fetch a PaymentIntent, you automatically get the latest Charge in the charges collection so you can access it via pi.charges.data[0] for example. You can also use the List Charges [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list) and then get all charges related to a given PaymentIntent".

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/issues/927